# unable to load script HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an index.html file with the following text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Wade Game Engine</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="wade_1.5.js"></script>
    <script src="wade.ifx_1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="wade.particles_1.0.1.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            wade.init('app.js');
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="border:0; width:800px; height:600px;">
        <div id="wade_main_div" width="800" height="600" tabindex="1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="chromeFix"></div>
    <div id="chromeFix2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to run this using a browser (tried with google chrome and internet explorer) it just pops a window saying:

unable to load main app script app.js

So I assume the problem is here:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        wade.init('app.js');
    });
</script>
```

But I can't understand what's the problem...
Could anyone help me with this? It's driving me insane!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that there is an error in app.js (so it isn't a valid .js file), or it could be that your browser is not allowing you to load local scripts asynchronously.

With Chrome, you could add --allow-file-access-from-files as a command line argument. Note that you only need to do this if you're using local files - if the files are hosted on a web server, it should just work without all this.

Alternatively, you can include app.js with the other script tags that you have in your HTML file, and just call `wade.init()` without passing 'app.js' to it

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an `app.js` file? I haven't used this game engine but looking at its [documentation](http://www.clockworkchilli.com/index.php/developers/documentation?docs=symbols/Wade.html), it appears that the `init()` method takes a mandatory parameter `appScript`, containing the filename of the app. In your case this would be `app.js`.

Make sure that you have the file `app.js` included in the same directory as your `index.html` file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I do have it so that isn't the issue :(

Comment: In `app.js` do you define a function `App()` like in this [example](http://www.clockworkchilli.com/index.php/developers/walkthrough/memory#section1)? So something like `App = function() { this.load = function() { ... }; this.init = function() { ... }; ... };`